# Ionic 5 force light mode for certain page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

Looking to off Dark mode for certain page only.

Referring to [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/dark-mode), below method doesn't work, there's no dark class showing in document body.

```
document.body.classList.toggle('dark', false);
```

Any solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be doable by doing it with

```
document.body.classList.toggle('dark', false);
```

to enable the Darkmode. You need to do this in the .ts file of your component. If you're using Ionic in Combination with Angular.

EDIT 1:

change your ionViewDidEnter to this:

```
async ionViewDidEnter() {
    await this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          document.body.classList.toggle('dark', false);
    })
}
```

Comment: async ionViewDidEnter() {
    await this.platform.ready();
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark', false);
  }

Comment: I'm need to force disable dark mode on certain page and had it done in .ts file. The page was still in dark mode.